# how to convert image from int array into uri?

Tags: android, uri

I have some images from drawable in an int array and now i want to convert each image from int array into URI. Can anybody tell me how can i do this. Thanks in advance.
    Here is my array

```
 int mBitmapIds = new int[]{ R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
                        R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Uri[] uris = new Uri[mBitmapIds.lenght];
for (int i = 0; i < mBitmapIds.lenght; i++) {
  uris[i] = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.here/drawable/"+mBitmpaIds[i[);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
int mBitmapIds = new int[]{ R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
                        R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d };
Uri[] uris = new Uri[4]:

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    uris[i] = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + mBitmapIds[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String PACKAGE="com.yourpackage";    

URI getResourceUri(int resId) {
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+PACKAGE+"/" + resId);
}


URI[] getUris(int[] resIds) {
    URI[] uris=new URI[resIds.length];
    for (int i=0, len=resIds.length; i<len; i++) uris[i]=getResourceUri(resIds[i]);
    return uris;
}
```